# Saving Selenium Test Suite

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm trying to save several test cases as test suite.
 When I open a saved file it has only one test case in it, no mater how I save my test cases.
 It is a bug? 
Am I doing something wrong? 
Or I don't understand the purpose of Suite in Selenium IDE?
 The idea is write many test cases and save it as a single test suite.

Answer (score 2):

Test suite is combination of test cases.
create test cases and then save it. At end save it as test suite.
when you open this test suite you will see all test cases which are saved under it.

Answer (score 1):

I also find that the concept of "suite" in Selenium is a bit misleading.
The best way to understand it is to create 3-4 test cases, but save only the first one; then save the suite and take a look at the XML files that are generated.

You will see that the tests are all in the suite, but that all of them, except the first one, will have any reference to the individual test case files since you have not saved them yet.
So the correct procedure I follow is:

1. Create a folder
2. Create a series of test cases and save each of them individually
   inside that folder
3. Finally save the suite inside that folder as well

Now, when you load the suite, all test cases will be there and will work as expected.